# "InvalidOperationException : Connection must be valid and open" On MySqlConnection

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, select, mariadb

I was working on a `VB.Net` project (first time, I was previously working in `VBA`) and I seem to have trouble establishing connecion with a MariaDB/MySQL database.
I wanted to get all rows for one column to use it as source for a ComboBox named `CBClient` in a Form

Here my codes so far:

First class: `ClassSQL`

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data.Types

Public Class ClassSQL
    Public Shared ConfigSQL As String = 
        "DATABASE=(My actual DB);DATA SOURCE=(IP of the server);USER ID=(UserID);PASSWORD=(Password)"

    Public Shared ConnectDB As New MySqlConnection(ConfigSQL)
End Class
```

And the Form class:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class NewDossier
    Private Sub NewDossier_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GetCBClient()
    End Sub

    Sub GetCBClient()
        ClassSQL.ConnectDB.Open()

        Dim Requete As String = "SELECT NomClient FROM MSClients"
        Dim Query As New MySqlCommand(Requete, ClassSQL.ConnectDB)
        Dim rs As MySqlDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader

        Do While rs.Read
            CBClient.Items.Add(rs.GetString("NomClient"))
        Loop

        ClassSQL.ConnectDB.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

On `ClassSQL.ConnectDB.Open()` in the Form class I have the exception:

> InvalidOperationException : Connection must be valid and open

Is my connection wrong somehow? Or is it something I did wrong?
Is there a way to specify the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ADO.Net, it is not generally a good idea to try to re-use the same connection object throughout an application, because of a feature called Connection Pooling. The connector is already managing this for you. Instead, *it really is better to just create a new connection instance for most queries*. Just keep the connection string handy and re-use that. This works especially well in conjunction with the `IDisposable`/`Using` pattern.

Additionally, it's a good idea to put your queries in the same Class or Module as your connection string, isolated from the rest of the application, where each query is a function that returns the data and (usually) accepts an argument telling it what data to find.

```vb
Public Module SQL
    'Making this private helps ensure you remember to put database activities here in this class.
    Private ConnectionString As String = "DATABASE=(My actual DB);DATA SOURCE=(IP of the server);USER ID=(UserID);PASSWORD=(Password)"

    'You could also design this function to return a DataTable object, if Iterator blocks aren't your thing
    Public Iterator Function GetMSClients() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Dim Requete As String = "SELECT NomClient FROM MSClients"

        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString), _
              cmd As New MySqlCommand(Requete, cn)
            cn.Open()

            Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While rdr.Read()
                     Yield rdr.GetString("NomClient")
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

End Module

Public Class NewDossier
    Private Sub NewDossier_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CBClient.Items.AddRange(SQL.GetMSClients().ToArray())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for all your tips and your code ! You really helped me here !

Now I just have to understand all that code but you really helped me do what I wanted.

Comment: @Yoleo  The first sentence *(...) it is not generally a good idea to try to re-use the same connection object throughout an application (...)*,  that's more that just *best practice*. That's the hidden source of a number of problems and, not least, very bad performace in many situations.